# Почему input и button выпадают из div?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

В общем нужно сделать так, чтобы в div находился input и button (типо как строка поика, но еще с background в ). Но по каким-то причинам они выпадают. Я подозреваю это из за flex-ов.

```css
body{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
.all-wrapper{
 width: 100%;
 height: 1892px;
}
.control-panel{
 width: 100%;
 height: 28px;
 background-color: #424242;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 text-align: right;
}
.control-panel .ctLink{
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.wrapper-lim{
 width: 1560px;
 border: 1px solid orange;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 112px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 background: linear-gradient(0deg, #ebebeb, #fff)
}
.logo{
 width: 136px;
 height: 74px;
 display: block;
 background-image: url(photos/logo.png);
 margin-right: 65px;
}
.another-lim{
 display: flex;
}
.search{
 width: 458px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #79b260;
 border: 1px solid;
}
#sear{
 width: 326px;
 height: 32px;
}
#butSearch{
 width: 126px;
 height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="Script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="all-wrapper">
  <div class="control-panel">
   <div class="wrapper-lim">
    <a href="" class="ctLink">Sing in</a>
    <a href="" class="ctLink">My Account</a>
    <a href="" class="ctLink">Order Status</a>
    <a href="" class="ctLink">Help</a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <header class="ant">
   <div class="wrapper-lim another-lim">
    <a href="" class="logo"></a>
    <div class="search"></div>
     <input type="text" id="sear">
     <button id="butSearch">Search</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут у Вас ошибка:

```
<div class="search"></div>
    <input type="text" id="sear">
    <button id="butSearch">Search</button>
</div>
```

`div` с классом `search` сразу же закрывается, то-есть должно быть так по-идеи:

```
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" id="sear">
    <button id="butSearch">Search</button>
</div>
```